# Perl Serial port access [Windows 10]

Tags: windows, perl, serial-port, gps

I do some small project with [Neo-6M GPS module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/GY-NEO6MV2-NEO-6M-gps-module-NEO6MV2-board-red-SN/352823175819) [datasheet](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/NEO-6_DataSheet_%28GPS.G6-HW-09005%29.pdf), in *Windows 10* to tracks **GPS** satellites.

A code snippet below demonstrates the `communication core` of the program.

I found that sometimes at program's start it does not communicate with **GPS module** and I have to interrupt it by pressing **Ctrl+C** a few times, to be able re-start it and to establish communication between the program and **GPS** module.

Sometimes it can take a few tries before the program will read data from **GPS** module.

**GPS** module connected to the computer through *USB to Serial* module [cp2102](https://www.ebay.com/itm/CP2102-USB-2-0-to-TTL-UART-Module-6Pin-Serial-Converter-STC-Replace-FT232-Module-/381374541932), [cp2102 datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/CP2102-9.pdf).

**GPS** module and drivers work properly -- confirmed with [u-center](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/u-center) software.

Can somebody *spot* a cause of the described problem with interaction between the program and **GPS** module?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);

use Win32::SerialPort; 
use Win32::Process;
use Win32::Console::ANSI qw/Cls Title Cursor/;
use Term::ANSIScreen qw/:color :cursor :screen/;
use sigtrap 'handler' => \&sig_handler, qw(INT TERM KILL QUIT);

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;

my $port_name   = 'COM4';
my $baudrate    = 9600;
my $databits    = 8;
my $parity      = 'none';
my $stopbits    = 1;

my $portObj = new Win32::SerialPort($port_name)
     || die "Can't open $port_name: $^E\n";    # $quiet is optional

$portObj->baudrate($baudrate);
$portObj->databits($databits);
$portObj->parity($parity);
$portObj->stopbits($stopbits);

sub sig_handler {
    Cls();
    cursor_mode('on');
    $portObj->lookclear();
    $portObj->close();
    exit 0;
}

cursor_mode('off');

while(1) {
    my $line = $portObj->lookfor();
    if( $line ) {
        {
            local $/ = "\r";
            chomp $line;
        }
        say "[$line]" if $debug;
        # Some data processing takes place
    } else {
        usleep(50);     # Allocate time for other processes to run
    }
}

# Data processing subroutines
# Positioned output to terminal window

sub cursor_mode {
    my $mode = shift;
    
    print "\e[?25l" if $mode eq 'off';
    print "\e[?25h" if $mode eq 'on';       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to log into the GPS module host and restart the GPS module daemon (or otherwise kill the stale connection). Doing a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> on the program isn't enough. Sometimes you're able to reestablish a connection because the preceding connection timed out.